# Visual Studio 2019 and Babel, Release Build Compile Javascript into ES5

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, build, babeljs, es6-modules

I'm attempting to setup an automated process for compiling ES6 JS down into ES5 when we build.

Its frustrating not being able to use all the nice new features in ES6 because we need to support IE11 for clients.

What I want is a simple automated process, maybe something I setup in a build script, which runs BABEL and generates the Es5 code.

When we go live, our release build uses bundles, maybe the bundled JS can point to that generated JS file, and locally I just run off the ES6 version.

I've never done anything remotely close to this, and I need to be careful not to break things. Our internal js library is MASSIVE.

Has anyone attempted this, or run into a similar situation?

What I'm really looking for is some direction and/or suggestions.

Step by step would be great too.

Thank you guys.

Comment: This will probably get closed, but you can pose your question in one of the chat rooms e.g. [javascript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript)